# Snapshot/Releas: versioning strategies for Maven projects

Tags: java, maven, project, release, snapshot

I hope to get some feedback on this problematic:

Say we've got Maven projects `A1` and `A2` and another 5 projects that depend on them (each of these depends on one, the other, or both. It doesn't matter).

As of now we publish always the same `SNAPSHOT` version of `A1` and `A2` so dependent projects are always in-synch with them.
The problem, as you can imagine, is that any change can be a breaking change which forces us to fix bugs as soon as possible.

On the other hand, versioning `A1` and `A2` with `releases` versions, can cause other projects to lag behind pretty quickly. This is the approach I'm going to follow though if I don't find other simple and effective solutions.

A mixed approach `snapshot`/`version` would be too much for us since we publish interesting changes (for the dependent projects) quite rarely.

Do you have any other approach to suggest?

Thank you guys!

Comment: "versioning A1 and A2 with releases versions, can cause other projects to lag" 

I mean nothing is stopping you from releasing frequently. Are you using maven release plugin?

Comment: Hi @CoderinoJavarino, thanks for you answer. Yes, we could release as often as we want but I'm afraid other projects would updated `A*` versions rarely, which can be tedious if many (breaking?) changes were introduces.

Comment: ...and no I don't use maven-release-plugin. How can it be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Standard advice is:

- If you build a release version of one of your 5 projects, it should only depend on release versions, i.e. A1 and A2 should be referenced in release versions.

This is to ensure build reproducibility.

So I would avoid to *never* build release versions of A1 and A2. Instead I would build SNAPSHOT versions until the change is stable and reliable and then build a release version.

In the 5 projects, you can use Maven goals like `versions:use-latest-releases` to update the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! As I said a mixed approach is not ideal since they're internal project which are continuously evolving and don't have a real "release" stage. But the custom maven goal is a very good idea though!